# Como OCULTAR un elemento al cambiar de seccion SOLO con CSS

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema desde hace dias, tnego un h1 en el body, el cual muestra un mensaje.

Pero cuando cambio de seccion, el mensaje sigue mostrandose, se que se debe a que esta en el body no en la seccion, pero no se como hacer o declarar una condicion que oculte el h1 cuando cambie de seccion o area en mi webpage.

Agradeceria mucho cualquier metodo para darle solucion a lo anterior solo con HTML y CSS, o si tienes algun consejo que darme para mejorar mi protafolio como buenas practicas (se que hay muchos ID haha). Muestro el css del h1 y mi HTML.

H1 code:

```css
 h1 { 
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Dubai;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vw;
  text-transform: fullsize-kana;
  animation: anim 7s linear forwards;
  font-size: 69px;
  place-items: center;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 7px 7px 30px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 50px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }

  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
    

  }
  
  75% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
    

  }
  100%{
      transition-delay:3s;
      color:transparent;
opacity:0;
  }}
```

HTML: `

```
<h1>Hi/.Take a tour for my Portfolio.</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div id="GridDiv">
        <a href="#AboutMe"><span>AboutMe</span></a>
        <a href="#Technologies"><span>Technologies</span></a>
        <a href="#Projects"><span>Projects</span></a>
        <a href="#Contact"><span>Contact</span></a>
        <a href="#Certifications"><span>Certifications</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<blockquote>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="InformationBar">
            <a href="#GridDiv">
                <img id="Logo" src="Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" />
            </a>
            <a href="#AboutMe">AboutMe </a>
            <a href="#Technologies">Technologies</a>
            <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
            <a href="#Certifications">Certifications</a>
            <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <section id="AboutMe">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <a href="mailto:rewardmnx@mail.com" target="_blank">
                            <img class="contact" src="Gmail.png" alt="Gmail" /></a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/christopher-paz-leon-745760202/" target="_blank">
                            <img class="contact" src="Linke.png" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="https://wa.me/960186410" target="_blank">
                            <img class="contact" src="Wsp.png" alt="Whatsapp" />

                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="Photo.jfif" alt="MyPersonalPhoto" />
                <a>Software Developer </a>
                <p>------------------------</p>
                Self-taught, passionate about development,
            <br />
                willing to develop or resolve 
            <br />
                any proyect, and give an excelent result. 

            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="Technologies">Tech</section>
        <section id="Projects">Projects</section>
        <section id="Contact">Conct</section>
        <section id="Certifications">Certifications</section>
    </div>

</blockquote>
```

`

Comment: Agrega un `z-index:0` a tu `h1`; y a tu `container` y `blockquote` un `z-index: 1` o mayor. Pero esto no es recomendable. De esta forma no se estructura las etiquetas. Todos deben estar en un contenedor, para que solamente el contenedor se sobreponga sobre otro que está fijo

Comment: No entendí tu problema, tu dices que se oculte cuando haces scroll a otra sección, cuando presionas el link, o en ambos casos???

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz lo hice, no funciono, posiblemente porque container y blockqoute no tienen jun color fondo, pero esa no seria una buena solucion ya que el mensaje seguiría cargandose por detras. Gracias por hacerme saber que hay mejores formas de estructurar etiquetas, intentare con eso.

Comment: @Yussef lo que busco es que el h1 solo cargue una vez, en la primera pagina de mi web, pero se sigue ejecutando aun cuando cambio de seccion...

Comment: Pero según entiendo tu solo tienes UNA sola página, tu no estas cargando nuevamente la página cuando presionas el link, solo estás navegando dentro de la misma página. Tu puedes ir a una sección a través de un link o haciendo scroll. Puedes usar `:target` para cambiar el css cuando presionas el link pero eso no va a funcionar si el usuario hace scroll